# Error "undefined local variable or method `logger'" when using `logger.info` in a Sinatra application

Tags: ruby, logging, sinatra

I have the following Sinatra 1.2.1 application code:

```
# app.rb
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  logger.info "COUCOU"
  'Hello world!'
end
```

and start the server with `ruby -rubygems app.rb`. When I go to http://localhost:4567 I get the error:

```
NameError at /
undefined local variable or method `logger' for #<Sinatra::Application:0x00000100d91f88>
file: app.rb location: block in <main> line: 4
```

Do I need to add or configure something to enable logging in Sinatra? Reading the Sinatra README and documentation, it looks like logging is enabled by default for `Sinatra::Application`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably missing a `logger = Logger.new`.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/logger/rdoc/

Comment: Indeed, thanks! My mistake: the README I was referring to is for the HEAD version of Sinatra, not the 1.2.1 gem version.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is in the not found write method, just extend the Logger class this way and everything should be ok:

```
class Logger
  # Make Rack::CommonLogger accept a Logger instance
  # without raising undefined method `write' for #<Logger:0x007fc12db61778>
  # makes a method alias using symbols

  alias :write :<<
end
```

Comment: @tekknolagi no. alias is not a method. There is no comma.

Answer (score 2):

Logger is not defined, to overcome it you can just use

```
Rails.logger.info "COUCOU"
```

or define it like this:

```
logger = Rails.logger.new
logger.info "COUCOU"
```